# How can I replace the built in WordPress editor?

Tags: plugins, tinymce, editor

I find the default editor included in a new WordPress installation quite clumsy and frustrating. There are a great many other, better HTML editors out there. Is it possible to replace the default with one of them without code changes to the WP site, or do I have to put on my armour and tackle the WP code itself?

Comment: You've got to go for the code, which is what we're all about here anyway.

Comment: Will anyone man up and explain what the down vote is for?

Comment: The down vote didn't come from me, but that's what you get when you ask a very broad, ill-researched question on this site. The literal answer to your question is: "yes, this is possible: write or find a plugin that does the job."

Answer (score 1):

The wordpress editor is **not** an html editor, has never been, and it is literally not "marketed" as one since the 3.5 release.

You can put a lot of work and replace it, but an "off the shelf" html editor will not be a good replacement without lots and lots of modifications, as the editor has many integration points with wordpress and you will have to replicate all of them with your editor.

Comment: I don't believe I say it was an HTML editor. I just say there are many HTML editors better, more appropriate, than it.

Comment: You basically say that you want to replace an orange with banana because there are better bananas. doesn't compute. @ProfK